# How do I call a method in my controller Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple method, that  is defined in my controller. I need to be able to call it from my controller

My controller code is as:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->except('_token');

$name = "form1_sections/" . $data['nextTab'] . "_form";
parse_str($data['inputs'], $output);
$rules =  $this->call_user_func($data['currentTab']); //need to call section1() 
//here if $data['currentTab'] is section1
$validator = Validator::make($output, $rules);

if ($validator->passes()) {
    return ["view" => view("$name")->render(), "isValid" => true];
} else {
    return ["isValid" => false, "msg" => json_encode([
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->getMessages(),
            'code' => 422
        ])
    ];
}
}

function section1() {
    return [
        'startDate' => 'required| date',
        'endDate' => 'required| date|different:startDate',
        'cv' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx'
    ];
}
//alo have section2(), section3() etc.
```

**$data['currentTab'] returns a string of section1()**
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you would in any instantiated class:

```
$foo = $this->section1();
```

Now `$foo` contains your returned array. You should probably denote the method as `protected`, as well.

Since you want to dynamically call a method based on an arbitrary string:

```
$foo = call_user_func('section1');
```

or in your case

```
$foo = call_user_func($data['currentTab']');
```

Comment: yea but $data['currentTab'] returns a string, and I don't only have section1(), i have 7 in total; making it easier to use the call_user_func.

Comment: `$data['currentTab'] ` contains the name of the method you wish to call?

Comment: yes! $data['currentTab'] returns 'section1' or 'section2', etc. So if it is section1, i would like to call the method section1()

Comment: yea I had that before like: `$rules=call_user_func($data['currentTab'])` but this does not work if my function is located in my controller.

Comment: Are the results of the section method calls something your trying to share across many controllers? Will they be used outside of controllers?

Comment: thanks @btl for all of your help. It turns out a simple command solved it: `$rules =$this->$data['currentTab']()`

Answer (score 0):

You should not call a controller method outside of the request/response cycle. And the schedule is made for executing commands, like the inspire command.

If you have a controller method which execute a piece of logic, put this logic in another class. Then inject this new class in the controllers action you need it and use it.

Then create a command for the task you want to want to execute. Inject the same class in the command and perform your logic using it.

Once your command works when using PHP artisan `your_command_name`, you can add it to the schedule: `$schedule->command('your_command_name')->hourly();`.

Comment: protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $schedule->call('Full\Namespace\YourController@method')
                ->hourly();
   }